# Quiero interpretar una base de datos de access en asp.net c#, pero me da este problema

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un proyecto es ASP.NET pero al momento de ejecutarlo me sale este aviso:[image: Este es el mensaje al momento de ejecutar el proyecto]

Aquí está mi código

[image: En la parte donde esta resaltado ahí es dónde se detiene el código]

Aquí esta todo el código que ejecuta el if
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que el `DataSource` le apunta a un archivo que ya no existe.

Comment: Estas hablando en el primer DataSource o en el segundo ?

Comment: John, solo veo 1, **edita tu pregunta colocando el código**; las imágenes no son suficientes. También prueba mirando este [enlace](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/594252eb-4196-4cbf-a84f-f2bd4bc648fd/error-no-se-pudo-encontrar-el-archivo-isam-instalable?forum=vbes) o busca `no se pudo encontrar el archivo isam instalable. c#` en Google.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema es porque necesitas ponerle comillas simples alrededor del path a tu archivo `mdb`.

```
connectionString: "Provider = ...; DataSource='c:/.../archivo.mdb'"
```

Comment: Te comento que realice lo que usted me dijo pero no dio resultado